# I am getting a blank and black simulator when I run the app

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am developing a sidebar menu application on Xcode 5. I imported `SWRevealViewController.h` and `SWRevealViewController.m` from Github into my application. I changed my `ViewController` class name to `SWRevealViewController`. After this change, I am getting a blank and black simulator when I run the app.

Comment: i checked in Deployment info and my main interface is " MAIN ". but still getting problem.

Comment: You probably need to go into your storyboard file and change the class of your controller from ViewController to SWReavealViewController

Comment: yes.. i did same but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the [instructions](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), and use the designated initializer method, like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *rearViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *frontViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    SWReavealViewController *viewController = [[SWReavealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController: rearViewController frontViewController: frontViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Also delete the Main Interface option from your target / General tab, and set it from code: